# io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: not a WebSoc ket handshake request: missing upgrade

Tags: java, websocket, netty, handshake

I wrote a server using `Netty` that communicates with `Websockets`.

Often I get this error:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: not a WebSoc
ket handshake request: missing upgrade
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketServerHandshaker00.ne
wHandshakeResponse(WebSocketServerHandshaker00.java:114)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketServerHandshaker.hand
shake(WebSocketServerHandshaker.java:161)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketServerHandshaker.hand
shake(WebSocketServerHandshaker.java:136)
        at chatserver.ChatServerHandler.handleHttpRequest(ChatServerHandler.java
:222)
   ....
```

Line 222 of ChatServerHandler is here:

```
private void handleHttpRequest(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest req) throws Exception 
{
   ...

     WebSocketServerHandshakerFactory wsFactory = new WebSocketServerHandshakerFactory(
                getWebSocketLocation(req), null, false);
        handshaker = wsFactory.newHandshaker(req);
        if (handshaker == null) {
            WebSocketServerHandshakerFactory.sendUnsupportedVersionResponse(ctx.channel());// .sendUnsupportedVersionResponse(ctx.channel());
        } else {
            handshaker.handshake(ctx.channel(), req); // <<< this is line 222
        }

   ...
}
```

What can I do to fix it?

EDIT: I'm using `Netty 4.0.15 final` final by the way.

Comment: can you give me example source code link

Comment: That's from this example if I remember correctly: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/WebSocketServerHandler.java

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the code in `handleHttpRequest` above the snippet you're showing is letting some non-websocket requests slip through, maybe favicon requests?